# Spanish character in CSV using Perl file handling

Tags: perl, encoding, mechanize, file-handling

I am using Perl Mechanize to store content from a Spanish language site and saving it in a csv file.

But the data's are not store as i expected.

For Example ::**EspaÃ±a , MÃ©xico , DejÃ³ de publicarse**

But i need to save it as **España, México ,Dejó de publicarse**

Need some guidance,Thanks in Advance

Comment: [Unicode support in Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html)

Comment: `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';`

I'm using it as one of the header file. still not getting the result.

Comment: Please, show your code. How do you open the input and output files?

Comment: The problem is in line 42

Comment: `open(FH,">>output.csv");
print FH qq|"$Name,$location"\n|;
close FH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://p3rl.org/UNI

```
use autodie qw(:all);
open my $fh, '>> :encoding(UTF-8)', 'output.csv';
print {$fh} qq|"$Name,$location"\n|;
close $fh;
```